# renaming a file with regex in bash MacOSX

Tags: regex, macos, bash

I have file names like this

```
223h123.sdsdas.png
```

which I would like to rename to

```
sdsdas.png
```

I am using this command

```
for i in *.png;do mv "$i" "${i/[a-zA-Z0-9]*/}";done
```

which gives me this instead

```
png,
```

I am using `bash` on MacOS X.

Comment: Remember that bash's `${i/this/that}` notation is *not* regex.  Have a look at the [bash man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#EXPANSION) and search for [`Parameter Expansion`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for an explanation of this notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing regular expressions with [Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).  They look a bit similar, but they are not the same.

A regular expression parser might allow you to make a regex-based substitution, for example:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ i="223h123.sdsdas.png"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo "$i" | sed 's/^[^.]*\.\([^.]*\)/\1/'
sdsdas.png
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Sed, the **S**tream **Ed**itor, has a **s**ubstitute command that takes a Basic Regular Expression and replaces `\1` with the first bracketed atom of the regex.

Alternately, you could use parameter expansion to strip off text to the first dot.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ i="223h123.sdsdas.png"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo ${i#*.}
sdsdas.png
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```